# When importing Sherlock, all List Item images changes

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm creating an application that contains a KML file built by Maps Engine with some custom icons. Here are the icons I used : http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/maps_engine_icons.png?w=300&h=216.
First, I downloaded them and made a screen that contains a list of places found in the KML file (the list would contain the icon, name and the description).

Everything was working fine until I imported the Sherlock library. After that, the icons changed to arrows, Xs and similar icons that we normally use for menus and buttons. I tried to rename my image files, but nothing happened. I did a search in stackoverflow but found nothing.

**Here is my code** *(when I import the sherlock bar I just change the Theme to Theme.Sherlock and change each Fragment to SherlockFragment or FragmentActivity to SherlockFragmentActivity)*.

**list_places_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/placeslistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**place_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icone1001" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placemark_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:text="@string/place_item_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placemark_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/place_item_description"
            android:textColor="@color/transaction_tags_color"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ListPlacesFragment.java**

```
public class ListPlacesFragment extends Fragment{

    PlacemarkAdapter placeAdapter;
    ListView placesListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View results = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_places_fragment, container, false);
        placesListView = (ListView) results.findViewById(R.id.placeslistview);
            placeAdapter = new PlacemarkAdapter(getActivity(), DataHelper.data.places);
            placesListView.setAdapter(placeAdapter);    
        return results;
    }
```

**PlaceMarkAdapter.java**

```
public class PlacemarkAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Placemark>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Placemark> places;

    public PlacemarkAdapter(Context context,
            List<Placemark> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.place_item, objects);
        this.context = context;
        places = new ArrayList<Placemark>();
        places.addAll(objects);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return places.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Placemark getItem(int position) {
        return places.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_item, parent, false);

        icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.placemark_name);
        description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.placemark_description);

        Placemark placemark = places.get(position);
        title.setText(placemark.getName());
        description.setText(placemark.getDescription());
        icon.setImageResource(placemark.getIconID());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I would like to mention that there is no error in LogCat (even after importing Sherlock), just the icon changes awkawrdly.

If someone had this problem or knows the solution, I appreciate that!

**I REALIZED THE SOLUTION:
id ICON of place_item.xml is unique for Sherlock. We don't have to identify any element by this name!**

Comment: Try setting the second parameter for your LayoutInflater's inflate() method to `null` instead of `parent` you may be having a "namespace" collision with Sherlock. If that doesn't work, change the id from 'icon' to something else in the xml and the adapter...

Comment: It doesn't work. The screen keeps with the same changed icons, but beside this, with null parameter it stays with a dark screen (maybe with the same color of the actionBar). Thanks for answering!

Comment: Hmm... Maybe a before an after screenshot would be helpful, that way we could see which ABS icons it is replacing yours with...

Comment: While I was changing things to take the screens you asked me, I tried to rename the icon id in xml. Now everything works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be encountering a namespace collision with ActionBarSherlock for the id of your ImageView. Change the id to something other than 'icon' in the xml and in your adapter, then ABS should stop assigning a different image to your ImageView.

Comment: I realized..I was storing in sharedPreferences the id, but it changes when I rebuild the project, but the data keeps the same, of course!

Comment: Yeap, I was trying to create a resources map, but I couldn't, so this didn't worked..in the end I've made a function that receives a key and returns the value, no data ever =)

Comment: Makes sense. You could probably just use a static `Map<String, int>` object if that's all you needed.